# Get 400 error when try to upload a image file to a collection

Tags: python, google-drive-api

I want to write a script to upload my photos to Google Drive. After couples of hours of digging into Google Document List API. I choose gdata-python-client 2.0.17(latest) to build my script. Everything works well, except that I cannot upload a file to a collection. Here is the exception.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./upload.py", line 27, in 
    upload(sys.argv[1])
  File "./upload.py", line 22, in upload
    client.create_resource(p, collection=f, media=ms)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gdata/docs/client.py", line 300, in create_resource
    return uploader.upload_file(create_uri, entry, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gdata/client.py", line 1090, in upload_file
    start_byte, self.file_handle.read(self.chunk_size))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gdata/client.py", line 1048, in upload_chunk
    raise error
gdata.client.RequestError: Server responded with: 400, <errors xmlns='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005'><error><domain>GData</domain><code>InvalidEntryException</code><internalReason>We're sorry, a server error occurred. Please try again.</internalReason></error></errors>
```

After hacking into the source code of gdata, I print some info for debugging.

```
>
Range: bytes 0-524287/729223
PUT TO: https://docs.google.com/feeds/upload/create-session/default/private/full/folder%3A0B96cfHivZx6ddGFwYXVCbzc4U3M/contents?upload_id=AEnB2UqnYRFTOyCCIGIESUIctWg6hvQIHY4JRMnL-CUQhHii3RGMFWZ12a7lXWd1hgOChd1Vqlr8d-BmvyfmhFhzhYK9Vnw4Xw
>
Range: bytes 524288-729222/729223
PUT TO: https://docs.google.com/feeds/upload/create-session/default/private/full/folder%3A0B96cfHivZx6ddGFwYXVCbzc4U3M/contents?upload_id=AEnB2UqnYRFTOyCCIGIESUIctWg6hvQIHY4JRMnL-CUQhHii3RGMFWZ12a7lXWd1hgOChd1Vqlr8d-BmvyfmhFhzhYK9Vnw4Xw
```

The exception raised when `PUT` the last part of file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would advise you to try the new Google Drive API v2 that makes it much easier with better support for media upload: https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/insert

Once you get an [authorized service instance](https://developers.google.com/drive/credentials), you can simply insert a new file like so:

```
from apiclient import errors
from apiclient.http import MediaFileUpload
# ...

def insert_file(service, title, description, parent_id, mime_type, filename):
  """Insert new file.

  Args:
    service: Drive API service instance.
    title: Title of the file to insert, including the extension.
    description: Description of the file to insert.
    parent_id: Parent folder's ID.
    mime_type: MIME type of the file to insert.
    filename: Filename of the file to insert.
  Returns:
    Inserted file metadata if successful, None otherwise.
  """
  media_body = MediaFileUpload(filename, mimetype=mime_type, resumable=True)
  body = {
    'title': title,
    'description': description,
    'mimeType': mime_type
  }
  # Set the parent folder.
  if parent_id:
    body['parents'] = [{'id': parent_id}]

  try:
    file = service.files().insert(
        body=body,
        media_body=media_body).execute()

    return file
  except errors.HttpError, error:
    print 'An error occured: %s' % error
    return None
```

Comment: I moved to Google Drive SDK v2. It works! Another question, is there a way to allow an anonymous user to download a photo with a secret link? Maybe I need to check the Permissions?

Comment: For anonymous access, you can simply send an unauthorized `GET` request to the public file's edit link which should be of the form `https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/<FILE_ID>`. Since no authorization headers are provided, you will also need to provided an [API Key](https://developers.google.com/console/help/#WhatIsKey) as a `?key=<API_KEY>` query parameter.

Comment: It doesn't work unfortunately. The response is : `{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "notFound",
    "message": "File not found: 0B2KSeJRpuK1PVm8xYTVaMHdVWGc"
   }
  ],
  "code": 404,
  "message": "File not found: 0B2KSeJRpuK1PVm8xYTVaMHdVWGc"
 }
}` Further more, I need a direct link to the image or a click-to-download link. Is that possible?

Comment: Just found that the `Download` action in photo viewer accesses a link like `https://doc-08-ao-docs.googleusercontent.com/docs/securesc/ha0ro937gcuc7l7deffksulhg5h7mbp1/0spj15t271ang5b0d6tc65p031hveq1d/1342058400000/14605084409704584131/*/0B2KSeJRpuK1PVm8xYTVaMHdVWGc?e=download`, is there an API to generate URL like that?

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no way to generate this link other than retrieving the file's metadata again (to get an updated `downloadUrl`). For the `404` error, make sure that the file is shared publicly otherwise, you won't be able to access the file anonymously.

Comment: Although I made the photo public accessible, and the updated `downloadUrl` still cannot be accessed by anonymous, response `401, Authentication required`. The only solution that I can come up with is running my own server to serve 1-click downloading.